# Files not saving on a specific type of Android device

Tags: android, android-file

I was wondering, is there any specific reason why app-generated files would not save on some Android devices?  The device I am using is apparently an Android-powered device meant for use as a display (rather than a phone or tablet).  Does this make a difference in files not being created?  It works on our normal Android tablets.

Oddly, the directories are created, but not the files themselves.

Comment: How are you checking to see if the files are created? Device File Explorer in Android Studio or `adb` are the best options, in terms of accurately representing what is on the device filesystem.

Comment: I checked with a file manager app and they don't show up.  Should I try the Device File Explorer or adb?

Comment: Yes, to be safe. *Probably* they will match. If they do not, then perhaps you are not indexing the file with the `MediaStore` using `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()`.

Comment: Have you verified that permissions to write to external storage are correctly granted?  I'm thinking that some purpose-built devices might not actually have any available external storage.